# Programmable Chat Media Filename (JS)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

The [Media Support](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/media-support) docs it mentions that when sending media you can: "Optionally specify a default download filename to help your application display the media to other users.". This is done using messagingOptions in Swift however in JS I cannot find any supporting documentation on how this is done. Currently, I am sending media as follows:

```
channel.sendMessage({
    contentType: 'image/png',
    media: fs.readFileSync(media) 
});
```

I have tried adding a filename with file, filename and name properties without any luck. As you can see the filename is empty in the Twilio console:

[image: Media attributes]

Any help on adding a filename is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not in the JS SDK documentation, I'll follow up with the Chat team here at Twilio and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', blob, filename);
```

---

According to the [FormData docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), you can add a filename as an option like so:
[image]

After converting the image to a Base64 string I created a blob from the binary and appended the blob to the form data as shown above. Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! Sorry if I was misleading in my answer too. We will make this clearer in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer was not misleading at all. Definitely got me in the right direction. Thanks